# Remove specific lines on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have the following:

```
<div id="test1"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>
<div id="test3"></div>
<div id="test4"></div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

How to make (div test1 and test3) removed upon clicking on the submit button?

Comment: Make an effort to explain or show what you've tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
button.onclick = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var ids = ['test1','test3'];
    var count = ids.length;
    while(count--) {
        document.getElementById(ids[count]).remove();
    }
};
```

```html
<div id="test1">test1</div>
<div id="test2">test2</div>
<div id="test3">test3</div>
<div id="test4">test4</div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you should have something like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3p2j19hr/) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit-btn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#test1, #test3').remove();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try with JQuery hide accordian, here's an example:

Put this in your head tag:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("#1, #3").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("#1, #3").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

And this n your body tag:

```
<div id="1">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</div>
<div id="2">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</div>
<div id="3">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</div>
<div id="4">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</div>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
```